# Why there is no List constructor using varargs?

Tags: java, collections, variadic-functions

Why there is nothing like this?

```
public List<T>(T... args)

List<T> list = new List<T>(t1, t2, t3, t4);
```

I always see things like:

```
List<T> list = Arrays.asList(new T[]{t1, t2, t3, t4});
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand your need. I have the same very often.
It's a JDK specification choice. You can create your own util class to do if  you need it regularly.

Warning : `Arrays.asList(vargs)` and `new ArrayList()` returns two implementations very different functionally.

`Arrays.asList(args)` returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. It's a minimal implementation of list with many unsupported operations.
Any method that modifies the ArrayList throws an UnsupportedOperationException.
So to have a shortcut way of creating a classic Java, you should write

```
List myList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3, t4));
```